# Spatial regression models: How to plot coefficients with CIs in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, spatial

I've been trying to plot coefficients with CIs from the results of my spatial error model (`errorsarlm`) in R. I can't seem to get it to work and would appreciate any tips!

For context, this is my spatial error model, which predicts life expectancy using county-level attributes:

```
emod <- errorsarlm(lifeExp ~ medianHome + socialCap + taxrate + unemprate + gini +
 race_seg + manuf_employ + povrate + pctblack + log(pop), 
 data = sp, listw = list.Q, weights = lifeExp_stdErr, zero.policy = TRUE)
```

What I've tried so far:

(1) `plot_summs` - and I've loaded packages `jtools`, `ggstance`, and `broom.mixed`:

```
plot_summs(emod, scale = TRUE)
```

(2) `ggcoef`, after loading packages `broom` and `GGally`:

```
ggcoef(emod)
```

However, both commands give me the following error:

> Error in if (!is.null(new_names) && length(new_names) != ncol(x)) { :
> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

**Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?**
Relatedly, if anyone can tell me the correct way to plot the coefficients in my model, could you also recommend how to plot both the results of my spatial error model (above) and OLS model (using the same variables) in the same figure?

Thanks!

Comment: See `ggcoef_model()`

Comment: @LSM-DAT_Linux - thank you! Can you be more specific about how to use it? I tried:
> library(broom)
> library(broom.helpers)
> library(GGally)
> ggcoef_model(emod)
x There was an error calling `tidy_fun()`. Most likely, this is because the
function supplied in `tidy_fun=` was misspelled, does not exist, is not
compatible with your object, or was missing necessary arguments (e.g. `conf.level=` or `conf.int=`). See error message below.
Error: Error in if (!is.null(new_names) && length(new_names) != ncol(x)) {: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed